# Finding the total value underneath a 3d line plot

Tags: matlab

So I have 3D filled line plots created in MATLAB using the following code:

```
  for k = 1: P
   for j = 1: L
    X22 = linspace(0,b*1000,N+1);
    Y22 = Yijk(j,:,k);
    n = length(X22);
    Z22 = contact_force(j,:,k);

    Xp2 = zeros(2*n,1);
    Yp2 = zeros(2*n,1);

    Xp2(1:n) = X22;
    Xp2(n+1:2*n) = X22(n:-1:1);
    Yp2(1:n) = Y22;
    Yp2(n+1:2*n) = Y22(n:-1:1);
    Zp2(1:n) = 0;
    Zp2(n+1:2*n) = Z22(n:-1:1);

    figure(100+k);
    hold on
    fill3(Xp2,Yp2,Zp2,'c');
    hold off
    title(['Contact force at fraction '...
        num2str(-1*((k-P)/P)) ' of base pitch'])
   end
  end
```

Which creates the following image :

[image]

I want to find what the total value for each blue line is, how would I do this?

Comment: By "total value for each blue line", do you mean the area of each blue shape? This could be done exactly using integration, or approximated by slicing the shapes into thin vertical rectangles and adding all their areas together.

Comment: Yes the total area of each blue shape, I am not doing this by hand though. I am using MATLAB

Comment: Both of those methods could be done using code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Summing the area under the curve:

```
sumZ = 0;
for k = 1: P
   for j = 1: L
    X22 = linspace(0,b*1000,N+1);
    Y22 = Yijk(j,:,k);
    n = length(X22);
    Z22 = contact_force(j,:,k);

    Xp2 = zeros(2*n,1);
    Yp2 = zeros(2*n,1);

    Xp2(1:n) = X22;
    Xp2(n+1:2*n) = X22(n:-1:1);
    Yp2(1:n) = Y22;
    Yp2(n+1:2*n) = Y22(n:-1:1);
    Zp2(1:n) = 0;
    Zp2(n+1:2*n) = Z22(n:-1:1);

    sumZ = sumZ+Zp2;

    figure(100+k);
    hold on
    fill3(Xp2,Yp2,Zp2,'c');
    hold off
    title(['Contact force at fraction '...
        num2str(-1*((k-P)/P)) ' of base pitch'])
   end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a matrix containing values, But I want a singular value for the area. i.e. I would like 4 values corresponding to each of the above lines.

Comment: In the end: `sumTotal = sum(sumZ(:)); `

Comment: And how I could get this plotted on the graph by the corresponding lines?